# Passed Variables in macro change when called sub is run

Tags: excel, vba, variables, pass-by-value

I have a master_macro that calls 2 other macros: (sub)calc and (sub)transfer. The calc macro doesn't need any variables passed to it, but the other one does and when the master_macro calls the transfer macro, there are several passed variables that are being modified even though they are passed using the byval method. these declarations are nested in a for loop because they are workbook names.

```
dpath = ws.cells(2,9).value
fname = ws.cells(i,10).value
set wkbk = workbooks.open(dpath & fname & ".xlsx")
call calc

tempname = ws.cells(4,9).value
fpath = ws.cells(3,9).value
temppath = ws.cells(5,9).value
set wkbk2 = workbooks.open(temppath & tempname) 'the tempname should have the extension

call transfer(fname, dpath, fpath, tempname, wkbk, wkbk2)
```

Here is how I start the transfer subroutine.

```
sub transfer(byval fname, byval dpath, byval fpath, byval tempname, byval wkbk, byval wkbk2)
```

I have breakpoints at the call point to step through it, to see what the variables are. Somehow the fpath and the tempname varialbes get switched. I was under the impression that if use byval they can't be changed. I noticed the error when once the transfer ran and broke at the 'next i' in the loop, it didn't save the tempname  in the fpath folder.

Comment: Looks like your argument order is backwards in `Call transfer(...)`. Shouldn't `fpath` come before `tempname`?

Comment: that did it. thanks. I didn't think it mattered because of the variable names.

Comment: You're confusing variables and arguments. `fname` the variable in `master_macro` is not the same as `fname` the argument of `transfer`.